CSS code to remove Hover for lookup fields only in Experience Cloud
for one of our customers we have a requirement to remove the hover functionality on the Experience Cloud lookup fields. We do use chatter so disabling these is not possible.
I've tried to add the following CSS code, this works, but it also removes the pop up for uploading files, which is obviously not what we want.
div.DESKTOP.comm-panels-container.uiContainerManager.siteforcePanelsContainer {display: none;}

Can anyone help me with the correct CSS code so that the files pop up is shown, but all the other hover pop ups aren't? I can't find the code to adjust the CSS properly.
Thanks
